# Getting Feature importance in multioutput random forest regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a multioutput random forest regressor and I want to calculate the feature importance on it

As read in some other question, somebody said to calculate the feature importance of the estimators. I didn't define any estimator as you would see below, I have no idea how many it created. That (for some reason) didn't throw an exception but, after running the code below, it says that object MultiOutputRegressor does not have estimators, but it does for RFR. If I try to access the original RFR in my model list I get the exception 'tuple has no attribute feature importances'

This code throws a

```
multioutput object has no attribute feature importance
```

```py
m4 = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor())
m5 = m4.estimator[0]
feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(m4.feature_importances_, index = X_train.columns, columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance')
print(feature_importances)
feature_importances.plot(kind = 'barh')
```

This code return

```
tuple object has no feature importance
```

```py
m4 = models[5]
#m5 = m4.estimator[0]
feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(m4.feature_importances_, index = X_train.columns, columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance')
print(feature_importances)
feature_importances.plot(kind = 'barh')
```

I only worked with classification problems before and I want to be able to display the feature importance in a similar manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m5 = m4.estimator[0]
```

replace `.estimator[0]` with `.estimators_[0]`
and replace `m4.feature_importances_` with `m5.feature_importances_`

after calling

```
m4 = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor())
```

You are supposed to fit some array using `m4.fit(array1, array2)` and you can see the estimators by calling `m4.estimators_`. You can then take 1 step further and find the feature importances by doing `m4.estimators_[0].feature_importances_`

Comment: hi Axois, thanks so much! I will try. The thing is, the model was declared, trained and validated before. That's why I thought that since the model it's trained and declared at the same time with other models (I'm doing a comparison between them). I wouldn't have to recreate the object

Comment: @Laury Sorto you do have to recreate and refit with the training data if you would like to do a comparison between models